# Castle windsor registering open generics

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I'm trying to register some open generics

If I do it like this it works

```
Component
    .For(typeof(IDtoFactory<>))
    .ImplementedBy(typeof(DtoFactoryBase<>))
    .LifestyleSingleton()
```

However if I try to register like this it fails

```
Classes
    .FromThisAssembly()
    .BasedOn(typeof(IDtoFactory<>))
    .WithServiceAllInterfaces()
    .LifestyleSingleton()
```

I don't really mind having to have an abstract base class to make this work but it's a bit of a pain nonetheless as I'd be happy with all the factories just implementing the interface.

I get an error like the following

```
Service 'MyProj.Factories.IDtoFactory`1
[[MyProject.Models.MemberDto, 
  MyProject, 
  Version=2.0.0.1, 
  Culture=neutral, 
  PublicKeyToken=null]]' which was not registered.
```

I'm using the latest version of Castle Windsor ~3.3

Am I doing anything wrong with my `Classes` registration for an open generic?

---

So this is incredibly frustrating

I went to build an example of [it not working here](https://github.com/bapti/CastleExamples) and it worked first time with no problems.  I'll have to look into my implementation at work because clearly there's some differences.

Comment: Could you include the failing resolution?

Comment: @samy - Done, I just figured it out a few minutes ago - my other registrations were far too generic and messed up my previous registrations

Comment: Ok, I think we should close this as "not reproductible" then. Good catch! :D

Comment: I'll mark my answer in a couple of days.  I'll also link my github working example as I think that's something that Windsor lacks is some good working examples of how to use the more advanced features like the TypedFactory

Comment: If you want some Typedfactory examples have a look at my answers on castle, I have been using them extensively lately and tried to help people with them. Good idea to document it though, perhaps you could also push the examples to the castle repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out my issue here.  In my production environment I had the following in a different installer

```
 Classes
    .FromThisAssembly()
    .Where(type => 
        type.Name.EndsWith("Wrapper") || 
        type.Name.EndsWith("Provider") ||
        type.Name.EndsWith("Factory") ||
        type.Name.EndsWith("Reader") ||
        type.Name.EndsWith("Writer") ||
        type.Name.EndsWith("Destroyer") ||
        type.Name.EndsWith("Helper")
    )
    .WithService
    .DefaultInterfaces()
    .Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.Is(scope))
```

This was messing up my other installer.  Once I removed it and replaced the registrations with something more explicit everything started working correctly

here is a working example on [github](https://github.com/bapti/CastleExamples)

Comment: I can't find your changes on a GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance that the error is not with the registration of IDtoFactory itself but with the connection between it and your Dto`s? Can you paste some more code?  In order to see what is actually going on expose your container from a property (for the test sake) and take a look at the component registrations. You will clearly see if there are any misconfigured components - there is such a property in the container itself.